# Conduction Period;Half wave rectifier;Battery

Tags: battery-charging, rectifier

How can we calculate the conduction period of the diode when a half-wave rectifier is used to charge a 12 Volts Battery  through a resistance 'R'? Given the input is fed by 34 Volts AC with turns ratio 2:1

My Approach:
we know for half-wave rectifier: $$\omega \times \Delta t = \surd((2 \times V_r)/V_p) \quad $$ $$Given \quad V_{pm}=34V ,V_o=12V\quad and \quad Turn \quad ratio=2:1 $$ $$\implies V_{sm}= 17V$$
Also we know: $$V_o=V_{sm}-(V_r/2)$$ $$\implies12=17-(V_r/2)$$ $$\implies V_r=10V$$ $$\therefore \omega \times \Delta t =1.08 \quad in \quad rad \quad or \quad 62.14^o$$
but answer is given as 120 degree ; so where am i wrong and how to proceed ....any suggestions..??

Comment: "Given the input is fed by 34 Volts AC with turns ratio 2:1 " what does that even mean?

Comment: That means a step down transformer is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a 17 volts RMS sinewave it has a peak voltage of 24 volts: -

[image]

Table content taken from [here](https://www.kew-ltd.co.jp/en/support/mame/detail.php?id=90).

So 17 volts (RMS) x 1.414 = 24 volts (the peak value).

If you assume an ideal diode and a constant 12 volts on your battery, you just need to calculate the points on the waveform that coincide with sin(\$\theta\$) = 12/24: -

[image]

Arc sin (12/24) = 30 degrees.

This means that at 30 degrees into the half sine waveform, conduction begins and, at 30 degrees before the half sine falls to zero, conduction stops. Half a sine is 180 degrees hence conduction lasts for 120 degrees.